# objective c sorting array of dictionaries by my order

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary

Here is the array of dictionaries:

```
    NSMutableArray *myArray = @[@{@"type":@"0",@"name":@"John"},@{@"type":@"1",@"name":@"Michael"},@{@"type":@"1",@"name":@"Jack"},@{@"type":@"0",@"name":@"Kate"},@{@"type":@"1",@"name":@"Alex"}];
```

What is I need to sort this array of dicts by that order (by value of "type"): 0,1,0,1 and the last element which will remain.

Comment: Sorting algorithm doesn't work that way, but rather >, >=, ==, <=, <. Why don't you split the dictionaries into two arrays (of type 0 and 1) and then combine the elements of the two in the result (like a zipper)?

Comment: I use it to make swipe to delete button in table view with two custom cells. I've tried with arrays but it makes a lot of problems after deleting one element from array. Problems with reload data and some more. So I want to try to combine from two arrays only one but after deleting one element from that main array I have to sort it again for my cells order.

Comment: it's all about how you keep & 'serve' your data. I'd keep two separate arrays.  For even indexPath.row you serve from type = 0 and for the odd ones from type = 1.